# convert string long format to long format

Tags: java, android, date

here is my date coming from server and store it is in string createddate:

```
createdDate = getIntent().getStringExtra("CreatedDate");
```

here createddate coming as `"1586503375033"`

when i send the created date to server i will be send as `1586503375033`

```
jsonobject.put("createdDate",createdDate);
```

i'm sending that createdDate like above

how to remove double quotes and send it as long format

Comment: Please think again. 1586503375033 is quite unreadable and meaningless to humans who want to debug or check. Consider sending ISO 8601 format in UTC: `2020-04-10T07:22:55.033Z`.

Answer (score 3):

`Long.parseLong(String);`
This will do the job

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `String` to a `Long`, with `Long.parseLong(createdDate)`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert String to long using Long.valueOf(String):

```
String text = "121315465465465465"; // example String
long value = Long.valueOf(text);
```

Comment: sorry.. fixed ;) @ArvindKumarAvinash